# How to recognize rectangle in UIImage?

Tags: objective-c, ios, image-processing

I need to crop an image to some rectangle. The image is taken from the iphone camera and the rectangle is pretty clear. I don't want to use OpenCV since it is too complicated.

how can I do this?

here is an example of the image:

[image]

Comment: It's not as easy as you may think. Unless you are already familiar with image processing I would strongly suggest using something 3rd party, like OpenCV

Comment: i dont know how to use opencv, and i dont have time for this, thats why i asked something other than opencv

Comment: I don't think writing image processing yourself will take less time

Comment: go with opencv it will save you time

Comment: My answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10623563/19679 provides a partial solution for picking out paper in an image, but it's not completely reliable. As I comment there, you're probably going to want to use something like a closing operation, thresholding, edge detection, and a Hough transform to establish the location of your piece of paper here. I'm working on a means of doing this, but in the meantime OpenCV is probably going to be your best bet. Trust me, it's far harder to do this yourself than just use the existing OpenCV implementation.

Comment: @BradLarson how we can do it with OpenCV in iOS, any helping link?