# Detect monochrome frame around an image for trimming

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, imaging

I have images that have a white border around them. I'd like to get rid of that border at runtime.

A simple but slow algorithm to do that would be like this:

1. Scan every row from the top down, stopping if a pixel in the row is non-white.
2. Do the same for all 4 sides.

That way, I learn the width of the white border on each side, and can trim it accordingly.

The above method is rather slow, I suppose. Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this? I.e, does iOS offer any functions that help with this task?

Comment: You might be able to pair up a thresholding operation (to remove everything that wasn't white), an opening or closing operation (to remove small features that weren't from your border), and Harris corner detection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530846/determine-the-corners-of-a-sheet-of-paper-with-ios-5-av-foundation-and-core-imag/10623563#10623563 . I have operations for all of these in GPUImage, like I show in the linked answer, but results might depend on the specifics of your images.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the best solution but as you said you can check the color, then trim. Here is a method for getting a color of the pixel in the image:

```
- (UIColor)colorOfPixelAtLocation:(CGPoint)position inImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    CFDataRef pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage));
    const UInt8* data = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);

    int pixelInfo = ((image.size.width  * position.y) + position.x ) * 4; // PNG

    UInt8 red = data[pixelInfo];
    UInt8 green = data[(pixelInfo + 1)];
    UInt8 blue = data[pixelInfo + 2];

    CFRelease(pixelData);

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:red/255.0f green:green/255.0f blue:blue/255.0f alpha:alpha/255.0f]; 
}
```

And code that trims:

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([largeImage CGImage], cropRect);

// Use the image

CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah, well. That's the part I already knew and which I described as the bad alternative. I also just found a similar answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056870/trim-uiimage-border

Answer (score -1):

I would just cheat. Say your image has a 10px white boarder around it, and the image is 200x 200, display it in a UIImageView with size 180x180 and centre it without any scaling :P

Comment: I can't do this because I don't know the dimensions of the borders of the images I am going to present. That's why I need to detect them at runtime.